# Iptables block host

Tags: linux, iptables

how I can block a whole host (internet provider), or allow only one country for ssh login?

Answer (score 1):

1.) Lookup the IP addresses of a specific ISP:

You'll have to use Google and search WHOIS records. You can also get hold of an ip2location database which should help.

2.) The command you need is: `$ iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.100.0/24 -j DROP`

Replace the IP (192.168.100.0) with your start IP of the range to block and the number afterwards with a netmask (see: http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/n/netmask.htm to work out what number you need) depending on how far you want to go, block-wise.

Answer (score 1):

iptables GeoIP extension allows you to create rules matching by country. Unfortunately GeoIP is not part of standard iptables/netfilter, so you need to hack around a bit to get it enabled.

[Here's a tutorial for Debian 5.0](http://www.ducea.com/2009/03/18/iptables-geoip-match-on-debian-lenny/).

Answer (score 0):

In [blogama](http://www.blogama.org/country.txt)  you can pick the country you'd like to block. (i.e)

CN China

Now, if you want to get the whole IP range for China, just query in the following address

```
http://blogama.org/country_query.php?country=CN
```

I found this a little bit tedious, so I made a script:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env ruby

    %w(uri net/http optparse).each {|r| require r}

    options = {}

    optparser = OptionParser.new do |opts|

      opts.banner = "Usage: #{File.basename($0)} [options]"
      opts.on('-c','--country COUNTRY', 'Country to generate iptables rules ie: CH') do |f|
        options[:country] = f
      end

      options[:list] = false
      opts.on('-l','--list', ' List all countries') do |r|
          options[:list] = true
      end

      opts.on_tail('-h','--help', 'Show options') do |o|
        puts opts
        exit
      end

    end

    optparser.parse(ARGV)

    if ARGV.length == 0
      puts optparser
      exit
    end

    url = 'http://blogama.org/country.txt'
    list = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse(url))

    if options[:list]
      puts list
      exit
    end

    query = 'http://blogama.org/country_query.php?country=' + options[:country]

    Dir.mkdir("blocked") if ! File.directory?("blocked")
    f = File.open("blocked/" + options[:country] + ".block","w")

    range = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse(query))
    ips = range.split(/\n/)
    ips.each do |ip|
      rule = "iptables -A INPUT #{ip} -j DROP\n"
      f.write(rule)
    end
```

The script will generate a list with the iptables syntax, based on the country you picked.Afterwards you can add that file to your rules

```
# Blocked IP range
. ./ipblock
```

**Caveat**: Too many rules will make you connection slower because the incoming packets will be matched against every rule you added.

Comment: blogama.org is now a parked domain. this could be a good alternative: http://ipinfodb.com/ip_country_block_iptables.php